# Python and Julia computes functions in different way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, julia

Python 3 computation for

```
N=123456789
sum(map(int,str(N))            ---> 45
```

Julia 0.6.2 computation for

```
N = 123456789
sum([Int(ch) for ch in "$N"])  ---> 477

N = 123456789
sum(map(Int, collect("$N")))  --->  477
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 10):

Because the python equivalent to your Julia-Statement would be

```
N=123456789
print( sum(map(ord,str(N))))
```

Output:

```
477
```

It is summing up the ascii-ord-value of '1'+'2'+...'9' - not converting each char of the string into an `int` and then summing up the `ints`.

This is not the same:

```
N=123456789
sum(map(int,str(N))
```

it converts the long int into a string, feeds each charachter into `int()` which converts `'1'` back to `1` (not to `ord('1')`) and then adds the numbers to 45

Comment: And `sum(digits(N))` would be the Julia equivalent of the Python code.